# Is running a VMware Fusion windows VM from a bootcamp partition faster?

Tags: performance, mac-osx, vmware-fusion, bootcamp

Is running a VMware Fusion windows VM from a bootcamp partition faster than using a virtual drive?  If so, is the difference dramatic or just 5-10%

Comment: probably belongs to Ask Different or Super User communities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer provided by http://twitter.com/vmwarefusion is "It will be MUCH faster from a virtual HD. Also, you can't suspend, resume, or snapshot a real disk partition."

Comment: Sorry. Are you suggesting the opposite?

Comment: The opposite of what?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the right answer but I would imagine it would be faster since it read and writes to an actual hard vice a virtual disk.  I would be surprised if the benefit were that dramatic though.  Keep in mind that with the Boot Camp option you lose the ability to suspend or snap shot a running system.  I would recommend you asking the [VMware Fusion twitter](http://twitter.com/vmwarefusion) account, for an official answer

Answer (score 1):

From experience it causes nothing but problems. If you ever need to boot to your Bootcamp partition you'll spend 20 minutes fiddling to get it Network/Wireless/Screen Res/Mouse restored because of the VMWare Tools install..

IMO it's easier to just use the VM as a virtual partition..

Answer (score 0):

It will be a tiny bit faster. "Raw disk mode" is what running directly from a partition or device is called and there's a bit less software in between the VM disk writes and the physical disk. In practice I don't think you would notice running just a single VM.